# Automatically Rename File if there's a Duplicate Filename

Tags: rename, command

I have a command that creates montages of images. Sometimes I want to save multiple montages from a series of images in a folder. The montage will be saved as `output.jpg`. But if I create another montage in the same folder the former montage will be overwritten with the new one.

`gmic %N -gimp_montage 4,\""V(H(0,1),H(2,V(3,4)))"\",1,1.0,0,5,0,0,0,255,0,0,0,0 -o output.jpg`

What can I add to the above command which will allow a montage to be saved with a different filename if `output.jpg` already exists in the folder? I'd like the file to be appended with parenthetical numbering, e.g. `output(1).jpg`, `output(2).jpg`, etc. But am open to other renaming solutions.

Comment: `...output."$(date)".jpg`

Comment: @jasonwryan Tx! That works.

Comment: This would be a better option, as it includes nanaseconds. Depending on how fast the program is processing the images there may be some problems due to multiple output files being given the same name and dropped: `output."$(date +"%Y%m%d.%H%M%S%3N")".jpg`